# Passing custom Data using Authorize.Net Payment

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am trying to pass some custom data through Authorize.Net payment. I am using `DPM` method.

The closest i could think of, is by using using `x_line_item`. However, this has a very specific format and also, the data is visible on the payment form.

I would like pass information which I can use it later to generate the invoice.

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Are you generating the invoice when the user gets back to your website?

Comment: Yes, I need to create a pdf invoice which I am generating in my website

Answer (score 1):

You should put it into a session or in your database. Your session variable will survive the user leaving your website as long as you don't have your sessions set to expire in a very short amount of time.

Comment: There is an option, where if the attribute is not recognized by authorize.net, it is passed through the POST variable as it is. I did something like this :echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"custom\" value=\"" .   $custom ."\"/>\n";